# How to nesting array value according to cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have array from stuff length. I want to put these array to specific box length.
How many box do ı need. For Example ı have ;
lenght array is (2,2,4,5,5,10,3,3,3,1) box lenght value is 10.
So My result will be

"You need 4 boxes and put them like this
1(10)
2(5,5)
3(3,3,3,1)
4(2,2,4)"

```
Public Sub Nestarray()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lenght() As Variant
Dim lenghtgroup() As Variant

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'First array
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lenght = ws.Range("D2:D" & lr).Value

'Second array I give space between stuff
ReDim lenghtgroup(LBound(lenght, 1) To UBound(lenght, 1), 1 To 1)
For i = LBound(lenght, 1) To UBound(lenght, 1)
    If Int(lenght(i, 1)) = ws.Range("H3").Value Then
        lenghtgroup(i, 1) = Int(lenght(i, 1))
    Else
        lenghtgroup(i, 1) = Int(lenght(i, 1) + ws.Range("H4").Value)
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't agree with your solution (although it is correct): my calculations would result in `1 (10), 2 (5,5), 3(4,3,3) and 4(3,2,2,1)`. Would that also be correct? Or are you looking for all possibilities?

Comment: @Dominique Yes its correct but as you show me there must be one condition. So as to classify my condition would be always nest higher value firstly. Your calculations is ok mine is not good.

Comment: İs there any idea? Where to start typing these code