# Vba 1D Nesting 2D array Join

Tags: excel, vba, nested

I want to join two 1d array in one 2d with condiditon.
Am ı in wrong way?

Conditions are;

```
If arr2(i) = 6000 Then
    arr3() = Join arr1(i) , arr2(i)
    Next i
Elseif
 arr3() = Join arr1(i), arr2(i), arr2(i+1) when it reach 6000 stop
Next i
bla bla bla...
```

Here is the results;

[image]

Comment: Loop the 2nd array, if the sum of the previous with the current exceeds 6000 then move to the next in the first array, otherwise use the current.  Please at least attempt to do the looping before coming here to ask for someone to do it for you.

Comment: @Scott Craner I just want to  know, am ı on the solution maybe there will be easy to do it. And want to know where to start. So ı have to do that `For  loop for arr2 with if statment` right?

Comment: I cannot understand your question... Are, so named, `arr1()`, `arr2()` extracted from columns ranges as you try showing? Or they are something as `Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)` and similar? Then, your code is strange... `Next i` after `If` without `End If`, `Join` does not do what you try accomplishing, at least, what I can deduce looking to your code...

Comment: If you iterate between the second array elements (13), based on what to match with elements in an array of 7 elements (the first one)?

Comment: Yes loop arr2 testing the sum with a variable that stores the item number of arr1.  have another variable that holds the sum, If the sum is greater than 6000. add 1 to the arr1 item variable and reset the sum variable to the current arr2.  Then put them together.

Comment: @FaneDuru Actually its same question as ı type yesterday.  These columns are just for figure out the problem . I am already generate these  array. Just try to join.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73730317/how-to-nesting-array-value-according-to-cell-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like I stated loop the second array and test, using variables to store which item in arr1 should be used based on the sum being greater than or equal to 6000:

```
Sub workForFree()
    Dim arr1 As Variant
    arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    Dim arr2 As Variant
    arr2 = Array(6000, 6000, 6000, 3003, 2003, 3003, 2003, 2003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003)
    
    Dim sm As Long
    sm = 0
    
    Dim k As Long
    k = 0
    
    Dim outarr As Variant
    ReDim outarr(0 To UBound(arr2), 0 To 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        If i = LBound(arr2) Then
            k = LBound(arr1)
            sm = arr2(i)
        ElseIf sm + arr2(i) >= 6000 Then
            k = k + 1
            sm = arr2(i)
        Else
            sm = sm + arr2(i)
        End If
        
        outarr(i, 0) = arr1(k)
        outarr(i, 1) = arr2(i)
    Next i
    
         
    ' do something with outarr
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(outarr, 1) + 1, 2) = outarr
    
            
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for taking your time and also thank you very much for Sub workForFree(). I am so pleased.